# Rewrite for same file accross mutiple subfolders when using multiple domains in one root

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I don't really know how to describe my problem in a sentence so instead I will explain with an example:

Lets say I have a folder structure that looks like this:

> /root
>
> /root/clientfolder1/testfile.php
>
> /root/clientfolder2/testfile.php

etc...

and the testfile.php is the same across all subfolders.

Now say I just pushed out a new file called testfile2.php accross all subfolders so now testfile2.php exists within all subfolders.

I add a redirect to point the old testfile.php to the new testfile2.php

So, in my .htaccess I add the following (Yes, 'RewriteEngine On' is set already in the .htaccess file):

```
RewriteRule (.*)/testfile\.php /$1/testfile2.php [R=301,L]
```

okay now everything appears to work fine at this point however ( and this is where things get tricky) in my htaccess file I also have rules setup for multiple domains to point to specific folders like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} domain-one.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/clientfolder1
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ clientfolder1/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} domain-two.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^clientfolder2
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ clientfolder2/$1 [L]
```

etc...

I also have a main (default domain name) that is used for my main site (files in root) lets call it main-domain.com

So the following works:

```
domain-one.com/testfile.php
domain-one.com/testfile2.php
domain-two.com/testfile.php
domain-two.com/testfile2.php
main-domain.com/clientfolder1/testfile.php
main-domain.com/clientfolder2/testfile.php
```

**Now here's my question/problem:**

My new redirect that I added above to replace the testfile.php with testfile2.php causes the following to happen:

**domain-one.com/testfile.php** redirects to:
**main-domain.com/clientfolder1/testfile2.php**

but I need it to redirect to **domain-one.com/testfile2.php**

I cannot get this to work...  and getting frustrated as I am sure there is a simple solution to this and I am just missing something obvious.  Can this be done and how?

Thanks in advance you your help - very much appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apache does exactly what your rules tell it to do.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} domain-one.com
```

If the domain is "domain-one.com" ...

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/clientfolder1
```

... and the URI does **not** begin with "/clientfolder1" ...

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ clientfolder1/$1 [L]
```

... then prepend the URI with "clientfolder1/".

Comment: Thanks for the reply but this doesn't solve my problem...  ` domain-one.com/testfile.php `code redirects to: ` main-domain.com/clientfolder1/testfile2.php `

but I need it to redirect to ` domain-one.com/testfile2.php `

Comment: Of course it doesn't solve your problem. It's what you're doing **wrong**. You need to **stop** doing that to solve your problem.

Comment: Can you give an example of how to do this right then?  Remember, I need to redirect a file across all subfolders and keep the domain redirects working as they should.  Sorry, but I obviously don't understand this enough to get it to work on my own.  Thank you!

Comment: Remove it (rule and conditions). I don't see why you have that rule in the first place.